# Passing targets in as a dependency and making sure they output something useful and meaningful to be consumed by next target

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am trying to get a plugin to use `run-commands` and I want it to run and execute a dependent task and pass the result to my command. In this case, I want to have a dependent target start up a webserver and keep it running.

I have tried to do the following and `nx graph` shows the right DAG but I am not seeing the output I want.

```
    "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "command": "./my-cli-tool --arg={frontendApp:serve}"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "frontendApp:serve"
      ]
```

I know that in a monorepo tool like bazel, passing around the target like `//frontendApp:serve` would do what I am expecting here so I am guessing there should be a way to do this in `nx`.

Update: To help with debugging.

If the dependency is running, it is failing silently. I can run it individually, e.g. `npx nx run frontendApp:serve`. I can't see the port starting up and being taken so if something is happening, its happening silently.

Answer (score 2):

`dependsOn` configuration looks a little different. It's in the docs here:

https://nx.dev/reference/project-configuration#dependson

Basically, you need have a local target which invokes the target in the other project.

```
{
  "foo": {
    "executor": "nx:run-commands",
    "options": {
      "command": "./my-cli-tool --arg={frontendApp:serve}"
    },
    "dependsOn": ["serve"]
  },
  "serve": {
    "executor": "nx:run-commands",
    "options": {
      "command": "nx run frontendApp:serve"
    }
  }
}
```

Another option is to use Angular DevKit's `allOf` or `concat` executors for running multiple things at once:

```
"serve-with-graphql": {
  "executor": "@angular-devkit/architect:allOf",
  "options": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "target": "web:serve"
      },
      {
        "target": "graphql:dev-server"
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/packages/angular_devkit/architect/builders/builders.json#L14-L23

- `allOf` runs each target at the same time
- `concat` runs them serially